# Парсинг Вики-текста на PHP

Tags: php, парсер, mediawiki

Как можно пропарсить викитекст, используя API MediaWiki?
Нашел вот эту статью : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext ,
Но не понимаю куда отправлять параметры.
Пробовал сюда:https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php, но не вышло.Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, написали "не вышло", пишите и что именно "не вышло".

Comment: Для начала нужно рассказать о том, что вы пытались сделать, потом показать как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, разобрался. Надо было вместо action=query поставить action=parse.
вот запрос : `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=parse&text==text=` 
 дальше можно развивать тему с параметрами дальше.